# Getting an object with objectid in PHP

Tags: php, xml

[image: XML]

From a GET request I got a objectid, in this example: 20140414153114207
Now I need to get the whole object with that objectID.

I don't have the knowledge on how to get that information. Can somebody help me to reach this in PHP?

I currently have this which is not working:

```
$houseid = $_GET["house"];

foreach( $xml[0]->objecten[0] as $key=>$value){
    if($xml[0]->objecten[0]->object["objectid"] == $houseid){
        print_r($xml[0]->objecten[0]->object[0]);
    }
}
```

I think I got the wrong code, but maybe somebody can help me with an example or solution? Couldn't find it on internet .. Hope some can help

Comment: Where is `$xml` coming from?

Comment: `if($xml[0]->objecten[0]->object["objectid"]` makes little sense - _which_ object would that be, in the last part? You are looping over `$xml[0]->objecten[0]` already, so the current `object` element is in `$value` – so work with _that_ inside the loop, instead of trying to access something else completely.

Comment: Hi, please could you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] *as text*, rather than an image of your debugger / web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Xpath expression to fetch element nodes from an SimpleXMLElement instance.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<data>
  <objecten>
    <object objectid="20140414153114207"/>
    <object objectid="20140414153114208"/>
    <object objectid="20140414153114209"/>
  </objecten>
</data>
XML;

$id = '20140414153114207';

$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($data->xpath("objecten/object[@objectid='{$id}']") as $object) {
    echo $object->asXML();
}
```

Output:

```
<object objectid="20140414153114207"/>
```